# Multiple object input in neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm a newbie to neural networks and want to program a NN which has to take a combination of 2 or 3 objects/instances of the same class (+ 1-2 additional attributes) as input and gives a yes/no classification as output.

Let's say for example I have a class with different attributes:

```
class Ingredient {
    enum Group {
        Vegetable,
        Fruit,
        Meat,
        Baked,
        Milk_Product
    }

    int carbs;
    int proteins;
    int fat;
    Group group; # 5 One-hot encoded
}


# Input
Ingredient ingredient1, ingredient2, ingredient3; # Each as 8-vector (5 OH + 3 values)
boolean sauce; # One-hot encoded
```

and a dataset full of different combinations (2 or 3 ingredient objects + a boolean for use of sauce), where each combination corresponds with a yes/no value for tastiness, which the NN shall be able to predict.

I assume an e.g. 3-ingredient-combination would have 25 input values: (5 one-hot-coded for the group + 3 nutritive) * 3 + 1 one-hot for sauce.

**My questions are:**

1. Is it better to separate the 2 from the 3 combinations and build a
   NN for each (2 combinations would only have 17 inputs)?
2. Is there a special way to connect the input layer with the first
   hidden layer (considering the input consists of distinct objects) or
   just standard full meshed?

I use TensorFlow as Framework. Thanks for every help!